# Noise does not display cover art embedded in the MP3

Tags: music

I have a problem with music app — it does not display cover art embedded in the MP3 file, only for those that have a *folder.jpg* in their folder :( I do not know how to fix it. I use new elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya.